# Unable to find the Windows "Desktop" folder from within WSL

Tags: desktop-environments, windows-subsystem-for-linux, paths

I recently downloaded Ubuntu on my HP Envy x360 laptop. I have worked with Ubuntu before. I am trying to navigate to my Windows `Desktop` folder in terminal, but I'm unable to find it. I type `/mnt/c/Users/'my username'/` but the `Desktop` folder is not located. This is how I find it on my old laptop and so not sure how they changed it in order to find the new path for `Desktop`.

Comment: ...downloaded, but not installed? What is "my Desktop"?

Comment: Do you see your user with `cd /mnt/c/Users/` + `ls`? FYI, if you're using WSL you should tell us. It's not quite the same as "real" Ubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1276304/edit) and indicate if you are using WSL, Ubuntu in a virtual machine like VMWare, VirtualBox, or dual booting Windows and Ubuntu. Then clarify if you are looking for the `Desktop` folder that is a part of Windows, or if it is a part of Ubuntu? Finally copy and paste the contents of the command `ls /mnt/c/Users/` and `ls "/mnt/c/Users/my username/"` in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Method 1: From Windows Desktop

1. Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **right-click** anywhere in Windows Desktop
2. Select **Open Linux shell here**

You should see the exact location of your Windows Desktop as represented in the WSL. In my case it was in `/mnt/c/Users/my_username/Desktop`.

## Method 2: From `terminal`

1. Open a Ubuntu terminal using wsl.exe
2. Enter `ls /mnt/c/Users/` to get a list of users and find your user name. The folder may be called `"my username"` or `my_username`.

**Note,** it may take a while for the list of files and folders to show up after you hit enter.

3. Enter `cd /mnt/c/Users/'my username'/Desktop` to navigate to the desktop.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I did method one, I was able to find out that the path to my Desktop was /mnt/c/Users/"my username"/OneDrive/Desktop. Should I be concerned that OneDrive is in my path? Will this affect any processing downstream?

Comment: @SterlingWright I have no idea. I don't use Windows much. I guess the OneDrive syncs the Desktop folder in all your computers.